# why are the converters being called again?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, converters, longlistselector

In my windows phone app one of the pages contains `LongListSelector`. In that `LongListSelector` I am using some converters. When the `LongListSelector` Loaded the Converters are being called as usual. But when I call `ScrollTo()` method to scroll to a specific item of the `LongListSelector`, the converters are being called again. Why are the converters being called again? What does `ScrollTo()` method do that causes converters to be called again?

Sample Code:

XAML:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LLSItemSource}"
                        Name="ChatListBox">

    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Transparent"
                  Visibility="{Binding ID, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                  Margin="0,6">

            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete"
                                      Click="ContextMenuItem_Click" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

            <Border Background="Black"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Padding="30,5,30,8"
                    CornerRadius="20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource dateStringConverter}}"
                           Foreground="White"
                           FontSize="20" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>     
    </DataTemplate> 
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

CS:

```
private void ContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string header = (sender as MenuItem).Header.ToString();
    MessageModel selectedListBoxItem = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as MessageModel;

    if (selectedListBoxItem == null)
        return;

    if (header == "delete")
    {
        DeleteItemByID(selectedListBoxItem.ID);

        if (ChatListBox.ItemsSource.Count > 0)
        {
            ChatListBox.ScrollTo(ChatListBox.ItemsSource[delIndex - 1]); // here I am scrolling to the last item that causes converters to be called again
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share code snippet.

Comment: I've added some code. @Nishi please check.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it's not possible to answer any "why?" question with any specific detail. That said, the most likely reason is that the list is "virtualized", meaning the actual displayed elements are created on the fly as needed. So your converter also will be called as needed. Regardless, you should never make assumptions about when or how often your converter will be called; there are any number of reasons the framework might have to call it.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, @Peter . Though all the items are in the screen (like only 2-3 items in the `LonglistSelector`) the converters are still being called.
But anyway, is it possible to recall all the converters after deleting one or more items from the `Itemsource`(an ObservableCollection)? Here I don't want to reload the `Itemsource` again or change the properties that cause the calls of the converters.

Comment: In the virtualized scenario, it can be simpler to write the code such that some degree of the virtualizing path is executed even when all the displayed items can fit. I wouldn't expect a _continuously repeating_ execution of the converters, but certainly it wouldn't surprise me to see them called more than once. If it's such a big problem for the converters to be called multiple times, then stop using them. Instead, provide an intermediate view model that will convert once, and then just provide the converted value always. (And I don't know what you mean by "recall all the converters").

Comment: I meant, I just want to remove one or more Items from the `ItemSource` and that will causes the call of all the converters again. Is it possible to do so without reloading the `ItemSource` again or changing the properties that are responsible for calling the converters?

Answer (score 0):

You are written converter for longlistselector items. On loading every item in selector its get executing to convert value on given template